# Why do I get an error that my class doesn't have an NSManagedObject property when it clearly does?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a `UIViewController` subclass, `MyViewController`, that has an `NSFetchedResultsController` and an `NSManagedObjectContext`. But when I go to create the `NSFetchedResultsController` it says I don't have a managedObjectContext property on `MyViewController`.

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Post", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 50
}()
```

Don't I clearly have a managedObjectContext variable declared right before it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializer of a property cannot reference another property in the same
class *unless* you declare it as a *lazy* computed property.

You also forgot to return a fetched results controller from the closure.

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Post", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 50
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return fetchedResultsController
    }()
```

Comment: What effect would the lazy variable difference do here fundamentally?

Comment: @DougSmith: A lazy variable is initialized on its first access, and not when the class instance is created. But that works well and a Core Data app created with the default Xcode templates uses the same pattern.